# How to make first row of tablelayout take whole space

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a table layout with 5rows. I'd like the size of first row to take the rest of the screen while the remaining rows take as much space they need based on the content inside.

My first intuition was to make the first row's layout width and height set to `match_parent` while having the other rows' width to `match_parent` and height to `wrap_content`. Needless to say, this does not work.

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like the size of first row to take the rest of the screen while
>   the remaining rows take as much space they need based on the content
>   inside.

I think that using `android:layout_weight="1"` on the first `TableRow` should solve the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `TableLayout` inside a `ScrollView` and fix the Height of your First `TableRow` which will solve your issue. Hope it works.

Comment: This probably would be my best alternative if there's no other choice. However, I'd like to keep the entire table on a single screen without producing a scrollbar based on the size.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as `TableLayout` inherits from `LinearLayout`, have you tried setting Row height to 0dp and setting layout weights for each one to achieve the desired effect? Like so:

```
<TableRow 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<TableRow 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
and so on....
```

Answer (score 0):

stick to your first intuition but add `layout_weight="1"` to the first row.`